# How can i adding image on edittext dynamically?

Tags: android

I am developing form design for share image through email,so i am developing  form for compose mail,i want to display some image in edit text dynamically ,how can i add image in edit text dynamically?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't draw images in a Edit**Text**.

Look for some WYSIWYG editor for Android, but I couldn't find one so don't know if it exists.

The only way to do this is by creating a browse button and select a image which you can display in a ImageView and send the image as a attachment.

Answer (score 2):

you can using this code

```
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("abc");
    Drawable d = img.getDrawable();
    d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
    ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
    ss.setSpan(span, 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    et.setText(ss);
```