# Remove Spanable image from EditText

Tags: android-edittext

I am working on an messenger type application where I need to add Smilies in Edit Text during chat.For adding the Smilies I need to add real smiley image not smiley string.To Achieve this I am trying to add Spanable image dynamically on a EditText 
This is my code

```
 SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("abc");
    Drawable d = img.getDrawable();
    d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
    ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
    ss.setSpan(span, 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    et.setText(ss);
```

I am following above code from link as [How can i adding image on edittext dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707251/how-can-i-adding-image-on-EditText-dynamically),

I am adding image in Edit Text and set the focus at end of Edit text where user's text end.Smilies adding fine as I want.
Now when I want to removing smilies / adding more text to Edit Text its given unexpected output.
Sometimes it remove text instead of smilies.Sometimes when I try to add more text/smiley it also again show old smilies that I already deleted on adding more text/smiley.
Waiting for comments . . .

Comment: where you stored the images whether you stored the images in drawable folder or downloading images from an url?

Comment: @Sankar Ganesh I stored the image in application's Drawable folder .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Try this.

String strMessage =  edtMsg.getText().toString();
          ImageGetter imageGetter = new ImageGetter() {
                                    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
                                        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(
                                                    R.drawable.happy);
                            d.setBounds(0,0,d.getIntrinsicWidth(),d.getIntrinsicHeight());               
                                            return d;
                                    }
                                    };

                                    Spanned cs = Html.fromHtml(strMessage+
                                            "<img src='"
                                                    + getResources()
                                                            .getDrawable(R.drawable.happy)
                                                    + "'/>", imageGetter, null);
                                    System.out.println("cs is:- " + cs);
                                    edtMsg.setText(cs);
```

Comment: And how do we get the smiley and the String from the edit text in one String